# fixed div at bottom in mobile screen

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I need your assistance in my html design.
So, basically i have a forms like this and it is working fine.

But when i open it in mobile due to keypad it scroll up.

I want to keep footer at end of the page. No matter it is visible when keypad is up or not.

Here is the image.

[image]

Here is the css code.

```
.footers {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
    background: #E9EDED;
    line-height: 1;
    text-align: center;
    color: #616363;
    font-size: 10px;

}
```

Comment: Use position absolute instead.

Comment: @VXp i will try and let you know.

Comment: @VXp I am away at the moment. Will try tonight.

Comment: @VXp Can you please type your code what exactly i will have to paste. It is bit confusing. You can write that in Answer section.

Comment: @VXp it didn't worked. fi page require scroll then all menu bar scrolled up.

Answer (score 0):

Yoy can't do this with pure CSS. You're gonna have to use JS/jQuery to hide the footer when keyboard shows up. Unfortunatly, there's no way to detect when keyboard fires, so you'll need some trick to do so.